# Unwanted shadow on Navigation Bar when pushing view controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

**Short Question:**
[image]

How to remove shadow in the blue circle when pushing view controllers?

**Long Question:**
My app is like facebook. There is a NewsFeed view, Detail post view, and the Page view. Here is what is in my interface builder: [image: interface builder]

The `HomeViewController` is the NewsFeed view, the `DetailPostViewController` is the Detail Page View, and the `FirstViewController` is the Page View. The `HomeViewController` is embeded to a `UINavigationController` which is embeded to a `UITabBarController`.

It is perfectly normal when I push from `FirstViewController` to `DetailPostViewController`. (Note that I don't use segue to push, but storyboard ID)
[image]

but when I push from `DetailPostViewController` to `FirstViewController`, there is a weird shadow on the navigation bar, like overlapping. But I don't want that. (Not using segue, but storyboard ID)
[image]

And this is my code pushing to `FirstViewController`

```
var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! FirstViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

How do I make the push from `DetailPostViewController` to `FirstViewController` look normal? I tried using segue but it didn't work. Been trying for so long but still no luck. Thanks.

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case, I used `inputAccessoryView` property to show my custom toolbar at the bottom of UIViewController

As it turned out, the issue was because my view controller was first responder in the beginning of the animation.

I think you should try  `navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)` 
when you are performing push. Or find some another way to hide toolbar before push animation.

For me this code fixed issue, in case someone has similar problem

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting the shadow in both instances and there's nothing you can do about it if you're going to use the built in transitions. iOS is adding it to the view hierarchy as part of the transition.

You could try using custom transitions: http://www.objc.io/issue-12/custom-container-view-controller-transitions.html. In this case I think you'd have full control over the views involved in the transition. But it would be a lot of work to remove that shadow.

Comment: Thanks. But I only have shadow on one instance (from post to page), but it's normal from page to post, and newsfeed to page. Do you think there is any headachy mistakes made in my interface builder?

Comment: In all the images you posted there is a shadow... look further down the page. I think it's just the contrast is different on one at the top so it's not as noticeable. Check any iOS app - you will see that shadow. It's not an IB problem, it's just how UIKit works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm fine with the shadow of the view controllers (the normal white space shadow in 2nd pic). But I don't want the shadow on the navigation bar (as marked by the blue circle in 1st and 3rd pic). I saw the same bug in the Quora app when tapping on a search result. But basically all iOS apps don't have this bug, including Facebook, Twitter, stack overflow etc.

Comment: ah, sorry didn't read your question properly. Not sure what to suggest. I'd be interested to now if it still happens if you reset the navigation stack before pushing the problem controller? Maybe that controller is already on the stack or something strange like that? Other than that I can only suggest maybe trying to isolate the problem in a sample project and filing a bug if the problem persists.

Comment: :( thanks for your suggestion. Ill try resetting it to see if it works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: brother how can you solve this problem plz.....explained me....i have suffered from these problem plz...help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .AppWhiteColor
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.MontBold(17), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.AppBlackColor]

        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Please try this do color of navigation bar

Answer (score -1):

Try using this to push using navigation controller

```
let vc = TwoViewController(nibName: "TwoViewController", bundle: nil)
     navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Check this tutorial [NavigationController](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Navigation-Controller)

Comment: Thanks. but I am using storyboard instead of xib. And what is the difference between this and my code?